# Build languages in liferay with bing translator not working for other languages except for language_en.properties

Tags: localization, liferay

I have created Language.properties in content(src/content) folder of the plugin portlet project.

Subscribed to microsoft bing translator in Microsoft azure market place.

Added the following credentials in portal-ext.properties

```
microsoft.translator.client.id= 
microsoft.translator.client.secret=
```

Deployed the portlet after server restart.

None of the propertie files except the Language_en.properties have been translated.

All property files have been generated like this.

```
sub-unit=Sub Unit (Automatic Copy)
sup-name=Supervisor Name (Automatic Copy)
supervisor=Supervisor (Automatic Copy)
```

Comment: Did you run build-languages target from your build.xml??

Comment: Yes Danish..<target name="build-lang">

 <antcall target="build-lang-cmd">

 <param name="lang.dir" value="docroot/WEB-INF/src/content" />

 <param name="lang.file" value="Language" />

 </antcall>

 </target> I have added the above lines in build.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same and I was getting same problem.

After debuggig the source code I came to know that it was not picking up the values of microsoft.translator.client.id and microsoft.translator.client.secret.

I had placed these values in portal-ext.properties and restarted the server but still it was not able to read these values.

So I have tried placing values in portal-ext.properties of  **<>/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes** and after that I build the languages using *ant build-lang* command and it worked properly.

you can get some help about portal-ext.properties from [here](http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2014/09/portal-properties-and-portal-ext.html).

I know its too late but batter to answer so others can get some help.